How to model heterogenenous count data?
I have been trying different models to model highly variable count data (mean 8.5, variance 144.3), that is grouped by participant (each participant took between 4 and 16 tests). Within each participant the error counts are also highly variable.
I am interested in whether there is a single model that can accurately capture this data. A generalized poisson model gives the lowest AIC/BIC values (though very similar to a negative binomial model (nbinom1 in glmmTBB).
total_errors_mdl_e3a_genp <- glmmTMB(
  formula = total_errors ~ version + (1 | participant_id) + (1 | piece) + (1 | order), 
  data = total_errors_table_e3, 
  family = genpois()
)  

But when checking model diagnostics the residuals are skewed and I'm sceptical about the model outputs, though I'm not sure how big a problem it is.

Our experiment involves pianists sight reading pieces of music. Our hypothesis is that version 2 leads to fewer errors when participants are challenged and has no effect when the test is easy. To test that we gave each participant sets of pieces of escalating difficulty, continuing until they either reached the final level or couldn't progress any further.
While we can split the data so we filter out 'easy' test results and just look at participant data when under a max level of challenge — my hope is that there's some way of modelling the entire data set to test this hypothesis. Any help or guidance is really appreciated.

I would absolutely go with the negbin model. Note that for count data with high overdispersion, the residuals will absolutely be skewed - if your fit for the expectation is 2.3, then the residuals cannot be lower than -2.3, but they can take arbitrarily large positive values. Similarly, a normal q-q-plot is not overly informative in this situation.
